# Microsoft identity confirm return InvalidToken on Ubuntu server

Tags: c#, identity, confirm

On .Net 6 last Microsoft Identity version.

I implement confirm user password for user by Identity.
Generate reset password token and send with the link in the email.
While confirming the user with that token I receive a success result, but  not always, some times it returns InvalidToken.
I read that it can be related to Encoding/Decoding issue, but it didn't help, also setting DataTokenProvider, but also it seetted by ".AddDefaultTokenProviders()" during setup AddIdentityCore;
Maybe it related to different machines it running, but how to check and configure it.

Important: service run in multiple instance behind load balancer

Comment: Does the password contains character 0x00 to 0x7F or character 0x80 to 0xFF?  Encoding can be an issue when using character above 0x80 or using unicode character.

Comment: @jdweng the problem that the same token work correct and not correct, just refreshing page

Comment: Are you sure the issue is with the token?  Maybe you are creating two connections and the server only allows one connection at a time.

Comment: Identity userManager return error "InvalidToken"

Comment: You may be right but I'm a doubting Thomas.  The error message could just mean the connection failed.